# object structure mismatch issue using json fromJson method

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, gson

So here is the issue i facing while converting a complex json to  a java
        object.

The incoming json is something like this:

```
{
    "view": {       
        "unit": {
            "sc": {
                "private": 6,
                "public": 6
            },
        "step": "PREPARE",
        "id": 3037,
    .....
}
```

Notice that sc has java keywords private and public as its fields.
On the client side i have the following code to consume this json.

```
String obj = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);    
JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonParser().parse(obj).getAsJsonObject();    
T objFinal = buildGson(dateFormat).fromJson(jsonObj, PrepareStateObject.class);
```

The PrepareStateObject is same as the corresponding json the only difference being  the sc object.

```
public class sc implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -952803010396503926L;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(sc.class);       
    private Integer _public;    
    private Integer _private;
    //....
}
```

When I inspect the jsonObj i can see the whole json with the sc object.
However as expected the fromJson method fails to populate the sc object due to  mismatch in field names.
How do I achieve this without using a mapper like jackson?

Comment: can you share stack trace here?

Comment: found the solution...

Answer (score 0):

https://shekhargulati.com/2015/09/14/gson-tip-jsonproperty-equivalent/

what i was looking for there using the  @SerializedName annotation for Gson parser which is equivalent to JsonProperty in jackson .